# Loading data to Ignite using spark

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

We are trying to load 60G of compressed data (in ORC format) to Ignite which is sitting in AWS S3. We are currently using spark to read data from S3 and writing to ignite (with native persistence enabled ). It loads data very fast when the application starts and load slows down gradually.

Is this the right way to load data to Ignite? 
We have tried hints from here :
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/performance-tips but without success.

Note : Both Spark and Ignite run on the same EMR cluster.

Comment: Have you tried to disable WAL [1] for data loading time?  

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log#section-wal-activation-and-deactivation

Answer (score 1):

- Set WAL mode to `LOG_ONLY` or `BACKGROUND`.
- Better yet, use 2.4 and disable WAL completely for the duration of upload.
- Make sure you stream data in multiple threads. If you're using `DataStreamer`, make sure to feed data to it in parallel.
- Increase the size of checkpoint page buffer.
- Use cache write synchronization mode of `PRIMARY_SYNC` or `FULL_ASYNC`.